# Fetching unique element from a set of elements in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

I Have a **plist** dictionary containing multiple arrays.
I will be fetching data from plist at regular intervals in my app.
This data is stored in the arrays.
Now what I want is each time while I am selecting an element or entry from any array I must ensure that ***element*** ***has not been selected or used till now***.

So ,is there any possible or viable solution to do this task.

Comment: There are many solutions...

Comment: Yes, it is possible, for example by keeping a dictionary of NSIndexSet of selected items. I'll attempt to show you.

Comment: By the way, 'until now' is since app open (and we can use memory)? or since app install (and we can use NSUserDefaults)?

Comment: @Cœur .Can you please provide any insight how to do it using NSIndexSet of selected items.Or any other way .

Comment: use NSUserDefaults to save used value. When using a value firstly check in NSUserDefaults if that value has been used or not.

Comment: @PareshNavadiya.I have approximately 3000 entries thus from what I think comparing elements might raise a complexity or delay issue.

Comment: Regarding this somewhat strange question. Essentially you must use a back end (a "BAAS") such as Firebase, Parse or the like to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
NSArray *tempArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *strX in plistArray){

int index=[arrayOld indexOfObject:strX];

if(index==NSNotFound){
   [tempArray addObject:strX];
}

}
```

//Temp Array will have Object which is not present in oldArray.

Comment: it will be gone once application removed from background

Comment: @PareshNavadiya.Thank you for the Code.But I want to share a scenario with you that will clear the picture.My plist has five arrays containing static data.I  might choose five elements randomly from the arrays .Now I have almost 3000 entries thus comparing old and new ones might create complexity or delay issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, a quick solution in memory with NSIndexSet.

```
static NSMutableDictionary *referenceDictionary;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
-(BOOL)canSelectElement:(id)obj fromArray:(NSString*)arrayKey
{
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        referenceDictionary = [@{} mutableCopy];
    });
    // simulating a plist dic. Use your real plist dic.
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = @{@"NSAppKeyExample1":@[@"A", @"B"], @"UIAppKeyExample2":@[@"C", @"D"]};

    if (referenceDictionary[arrayKey] == nil)
        referenceDictionary[arrayKey] = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    NSArray *array = infoDictionary[arrayKey];
    NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject:obj];
    if ([referenceDictionary[arrayKey] containsIndex:index])
        return NO;
    [referenceDictionary[arrayKey] addIndex:index];
    return YES;
}
```

If you need persistance when app is closed, store the referenceDictionary in NSUserDefaults instead of a static var.